# How to get timezone in this format? United States; Eastern time (GMT -4:00)

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

Is there a way to detect and get current timezone in this format:

```
 United States; Eastern time (GMT -4:00)
```

I tried with

```
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.toTimeString();
```

It returns - "16:17:15 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)". How can I get the country name with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: It's not difficult to convert the value returned by *getTimezoneOffset* to ±H:mm format, the rest of the information is not present anywhere in the supplied timestamp so impossible for a parser or formatter to determine.